# JQuery on() undefined function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, hide

After making changes from original to changed code boxes, I now get Uncaught Type error: Undefined is not a function. Any ideas as to why? Thanks

Original:

```
 $('.comment').click(function(e){
    alert("click");
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".slidingDiv2").slideToggle();
});
```

Changed:

```
 $(document.body).on('click', '.comment' ,function(){
        alert("click");
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".slidingDiv2").slideToggle();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way might be to set it to `display:none` in your `css`, so it is hidden until your click event ( `$('.comment').click(function(e){...` ) is fired.

CSS:

```
.slidingDiv2 {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. SlidingDiv2 no longer displays upon calling the refresh function, however as the Javascript isn't loaded/executed, there is no way to make the div visible again.

Comment: You're welcome! But I don't get your second point - your code looks like you that you want to see the div only if the .comment class (I guess it's a button) is clicked, right? Like this http://jsfiddle.net/6r1v5qbw/1

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Have a look at the fiddle I posted above (updated shortly). This has exactly your desired behavior - the div appears only on click of the button

Comment: I have that working perfectly on the page newsfeed.php, my issue arises however when I set the content of the div newsput to the result of the ajax call to newsfeed.php as the Javascript on newsfeed.php isn't executed/loaded during the ajax call.

Comment: Not sure if I get you right, but you can try to include this  $('.comment').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".slidingDiv2").slideToggle();
    }); in your file which is loaded via ajax

Comment: Sorry, I'm terrible at explaining things sometimes!. I have that included in the file newsfeed.php, which is the file that I load via ajax. I originally use PHP to include the file newsfeed.php into the newsput DIV on the main page. Everything works perfect at this point. Once I click a refresh button which calls the refresh function, it loads the contents of newsfeed.php into the newsput DIV. It is at this point that the slidingDiv no longer works. Hope this clears it up a bit.

Comment: Okay, have you tried to include the jQuery function into the file that is loaded via ajax

Comment: I've come up to a solution for my problem, however I'm running into more issues. I've updated my original post to include these. If you wouldn't mind taking a look it'd be appreciated. Thank you for your assistance! It's appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`$(document.body)` is not a valid selector, use `$('body')`